# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(ax) + bx}{\sin(bx)+ax}$ without using L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

By using L'Hôpital's rule I can clearly see the answer is $1$. But when I tried without using L'Hôpital's rule, I somehow ended up getting $a/b$ as answer. Here's what I did:

$$\begin{align} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(ax) + bx}{\sin(bx)+ax} &= \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} (\sin(ax) + bx)}{\lim_{x \to 0} (\sin(bx) + ax)} \\ &= \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(ax) + \lim_{x \to 0} bx}{\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(bx) + \lim_{x \to 0} ax} \\ &= \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(ax) + 0}{\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(bx) + 0} \\ &= \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(ax)}{ax} \times ax}{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(bx)}{bx} \times bx} \\ &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{\sin(ax)}{ax} \times ax}{\frac{\sin(bx)}{bx} \times bx} \\ &= \frac ab \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(ax)}{ax}}{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(bx)}{bx}} \\ &= \frac ab \end{align} $$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note that $\lim_{x->0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x->0}f(x)}{\lim_{x->0}g(x)}=\frac{f(0)}{g(0)}$ is *only* true if all of $\lim_{x->0}f(x)$, $\lim_{x->0}g(x)$ and $\frac{f(0)}{g(0)}$ exist. However, in your case, $\frac{f(0)}{g(0)}=\frac{0}{0}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: You *only* calculated one part of each of the $2$ separated limits in the numerator and denominator. Note that if you had instead calculated just the first limit parts, i.e., $\lim_{x->0}\sin(ax)=\lim_{x->0}\sin(bx)=0$, you'd get $\frac{bx}{ax}=\frac{b}{a}$ as an alternate result.

Comment: Сan you apply Taylor's series/expansion?

Comment: @zkutch I am not at that level yet and I am pretty sure this doesn't require that

Comment: @JohnOmielan So, is the first step wrong?

Comment: Yes, as my [first comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4889844/evaluate-lim-x-to-0-frac-sinax-bx-sinbxax-without-using-lh%c3%b4pi?noredirect=1#comment10432352_4889844) indicated. Thus, anything you get afterwards can't really be trusted. For example, my [second comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4889844/evaluate-lim-x-to-0-frac-sinax-bx-sinbxax-without-using-lh%c3%b4pi?noredirect=1#comment10432355_4889844) shows, using your same approach with the first limit parts instead of the second, would have resulted the generally different value of $\frac{b}{a}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks, I understand it now.

Comment: @HishamShefeekh You're welcome. However, note that your statement of "By using L'Hôpital's rule I can clearly see the answer is $1$" is not completely correct. As I show in my answer comment, if $a=-b$ with $b\neq 0$, then the limit is actually $-1$ instead. Using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) results in $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(ax)+bx}{\sin(bx)+ax}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{a\cos(ax)+b}{b\cos(bx)+a}=\frac{a+b}{b+a}=1$ being correct *only* if $a+b\neq 0\;\to\;a\neq -b$. Otherwise, you get $\frac{0}{0}$, which is indeterminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $a\ne -b$
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(ax) + bx}{\sin(bx)+ax}=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{\sin(ax)}{ax}\cdot ax + bx}{\frac{\sin(bx)}{bx}\cdot bx+ax}=\\
=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{\sin(ax)}{ax}\cdot a + b}{\frac{\sin(bx)}{bx}\cdot b+a}=\frac{a+b}{a+b}=1$$
when $a,b \ne 0$, though in this case initial fraction doesn't make sense.

**Addition**.

Full picture, (thanking comment), can be viewed from one expression using Taylor's series/expansion. Using, for example, $\sin x =x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^4) $ with $o$-little. Then, assuming $a^2+b^2\ne 0$, we have
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(ax) + bx}{\sin(bx)+ax}=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{(a+ b)x-\frac{a^3x^3}{3!}+o(x^4)}{(b+a)x -\frac{b^3x^3}{3!}+o(x^4)}=\\
=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{(a+ b)-\frac{a^3x^2}{3!}+o(x^3)}{(b+a) -\frac{b^3x^2}{3!}+o(x^3)}=\begin{cases}1, & a\ne-b \\
-1, & a=-b\end{cases}$$

Comment: For completeness, you may wish to also handle the remaining cases. First, if $a=0$ and $b\neq 0$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(ax)+bx}{\sin(bx)+ax}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{bx}{\sin(bx)}=1$, plus simlarly for $a\neq 0$ and $b=0$. Secondly, and more interestingly, if $a=-b$, with $b\neq 0$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(ax)+bx}{\sin(bx)+ax}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(-bx)+bx}{\sin(bx)-bx}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{-\sin(bx)+bx}{\sin(bx)-bx}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}-\left(\frac{\sin(bx)-bx}{\sin(bx)-bx}\right)=-1$, i.e., the negative of the general case!

Comment: Good catch, @John Omielan. I wrote it using one expression, though OP, possibly, is not familiar with Taylor formula, but continuing this way brings him to it quickly.